# Execute current buffer as bash script from vim

Tags: command-line, external-command, bash

I use vim for bash scripting, and sometimes I write a one-time script. Usually, I don't want to create a new file, make it executable, execute it and then remove it.

For instance I open vim and type this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ll | while read line
do
    echo $line
done
```

I did not save this file, I just use vim to simplify bash-scripting. I know I can execute a bash command via `!` in vim. But what about executing everything that is in the buffer?

Comment: You know you can edit the current command-line in Vim with `<C-x><C-e>` and execute it on write, right?

Comment: If you run bash with this option `set -o vi`, you can hit `Esc-v` to edit the command line in vi. Then `Esc-:wq` to execute.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I wrote a pretty extensive answer about this [over on stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40290101/3524982). The basic idea is that since the write command is about *writing* not *saving*, you can write the text in your buffer into an external program, such as python or bash. In your case, you would want to do something like:

```
:w !bash
```

or

```
:w !sh
```

These commands literally just write the text in your buffer directly into the program you specify with `!`, which is convenient because then you do not need to save a file. Of course, you may also do something like:

```
:w | !bash %
```

which saves your file and then runs it as a bash script. You can choose whichever one makes more sense for you.

Comment: Is there a way to provide options an argument this way? I tried `:w !bash -a test` but got "cannot execute binary file"

Comment: @St.Antario Hmm. I'm sure there must be some way, but my bash is pretty rusty (I mostly use windows). When I try that in cygwin with an empty `test` file, it runs fine for me. What is the command supposed to do, and what should `test` contain?

Comment: My actual case is pretty complicated, so let it just print the argument passed in. BTW, what do you mean what should `test ` contain? `test` is just an argument to `-a`.

Comment: @St.Antario Oh, OK I see. I thought `test` was supposed to be a file. I'm not really sure what to do. If you're trying something complex it might be better to just save it in a file. It might be worth asking as a separate question so you can provide more detail. It would probably also be a good question for [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 6):

Scenario: you are working in bash shell. First, make sure the local edit mode is vi:

```
$ set -o vi
```

Now, when you find yourself working on a long command like the following, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

```
$ fjhwfq this is my long command
```

This will load your command into a temporary `vi` session. Now you can edit it as you wish, and even add another command...

```
fjhwfq some long command
ls -l
```

When you have finished editing, type <kbd>Esc</kbd> `:wq` and the command(s) will be executed, for example:

```
$ fjhwfq some long command
fjhwfq some long command
bash: fjhwfq: command not found
ls -l
total 44
-rw-r--r-- 1 ropata Domain Users 24073 Nov 10 14:17 _viminfo
drwxr-xr-x 1 ropata Domain Users     0 Jul 15 13:57 bin/
-rw-r--r-- 1 ropata Domain Users   956 Nov  7 10:43 custom_env
```

Comment: might not work if you have a new macbook without an `Esc` key ;)

Comment: New MacBooks don't have `Esc` keys!? How can they use Vim then?

Comment: Now I've tried it, the new macbook touchbar thingy *does* show an `Esc` key when running Vim in a terminal.

Comment: Also, Esc is not the only way to return to normal mode.  You can also use Ctrl-c or Ctrl-[. https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-%5B

Comment: No judgement but if you're using vim without remapping your keys, you're really stressing out your hands for no reason. Look into Karabiner and Ergodox (software / hardware solutions) for this problem.