# How to execute a shell script from a line in a file with `%` in it

Tags: command-line, external-command, register, ex-mode, shell

I have a shell script on a line alone in a file which I would like to be able to easily execute from vim. Normally I could simply use `Y:!^R"`, but this particular script has `%` in it, which is expanded to the current filename.

- `Y:exe '!'.@"` still treats `%` as a filename
- `Y:!`=getreg('"')` is passed literally

Ideally whatever solution would be trivial to type, like `Y:!^R"`. My current workaround is to run `Y:!^R"` and then manually insert a `\` before each `%`, but this is work the computer should be responsible for.

The command I'm wanting to run is: `expr (expr (date --utc +%s) / 86400 - 7) % 15 + 1` in `fish`; in `bash` that would be `expr $(expr $(date --utc +%s) / 86400 - 7) % 15 + 1`.

Is there an easy way to escape special characters in an ex shell command, or treat what is typed strictly literally? I'm sure `vim` has this covered, but I've searched a while and don't know how to find it.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use `fnameescape`:

```
Y:!<C-r>=fnameescape(@")<CR>
```

But it may not be perfect if the command has spaces. You could also try `split(@")->map('fnameescape(v:val)')->join(' ')` in the expression, or some combination of `shellescape()`/`escape(…, '%#')`, etc.

Comment: Ironically, `Y:!<C-r>=fnameescape(@")<CR>` escapes all the spaces, but does _not_ escape the `%`s. Your second example w/`split`/`map`/`join` does work.

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer derived from https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10211/8846 - doesn't function in quite the same way, but `:.w !fish` does send the text to a new shell literally and returns the correct answer.

It also makes it easier to write short python or other language programs instead of shell script, which would be an advantage.

Comment: It seems you always find something just after you give up looking.